# How to "emulate" the Send button from addin on new meeting?

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an add-in for Outlook that has a "Create reservation" button. I would like to, when clicked, also send the invitation to all attendees, **even if this is a new reservation**.

I am aware of the `saveAsync` function from [`Office.context.mailbox.item`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox.item) but, as per the documentation:

> For new appointments that have not been saved before, no invitation will be sent.

Any idea on how would I be able to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot send an invitation until the event is committed. Until then, it is just a "draft" appointment.

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur, what do you understand by "committed"? Is there a way of emulating that behaviour?

Comment: Invites are saved when the event is created on a given calendar. As long as it is just a draft, it won't send an invite. In other words, the user needs to click Save or Save & Close before it will send out the invitation.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, thanks for the clarification. Is there any way for me to emulate that behaviour from an addin, using code?

Comment: There isn't a mechanism for that. The `saveAsync` will save the item 'in place', so if it is a net-new event `saveAsync` will save it to the Drafts folder. The invite (and placing it on the calendar) will happen once the user clicks Save & Close.

Comment: It sounds like you are requesting something like mailbox.item.sendAsync(). Which as Marc Mentions is not currently supported. Can you help us understand what you are trying to do and your scenario? 

Otherwise Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, I have an integration with Outlook and, by using the addin, I am creating room reservations in a third-party platform. So, ideally, when the user clicks on the 'Create reservation' button in the addin, the Outlook invite should also be sent.